# Number of seconds in a year time being miscalculated in Rails 5 as of Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I use `1.year.to_i` number of seconds in 1 year. But for rails 4 and 5 it has a notable difference of 648 seconds or approximately 10 mins. Is this change intentional, if yes what's the reason behind this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created and issue on GitHub and just got a perfect answer.

> 1.year is now provided by ActiveSupport::Duration and it follows the Gregorian calendar. Length of a Gregorian year => 365.2425 days which amounts to 31556952 seconds.
>   What you are talking about is Julian year which is almost 11 minutes longer.

So this is no strange behavior.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33978#issuecomment-424331247

Answer (score 1):

This is a constant defined in ActiveSupport::Duration called `SECONDS_PER_YEAR` and its value is 31556952.

To track this down here are the steps i followed in pry, may help you or someone else reading in future.

```
[8] pry(main)> show-source 1.year
...
def years
  ActiveSupport::Duration.years(self)
end

[9] pry(main)> show-source ActiveSupport::Duration.years
...
def years(value) #:nodoc:
  new(value * SECONDS_PER_YEAR, [[:years, value]])
end

[11] pry(main)> cd ActiveSupport::Duration
[12] pry(ActiveSupport::Duration):1> SECONDS_PER_YEAR
=> 31556952
```